# CakePHP and jQuery Counter on button click

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have written a little jQuery button click counter, i have got a little stuck as i want to submit my form to add a row to a mysql db (cakephp) and then if it is added update the value on the page, but if it doesnt get added to the db the counter doesnt go up.

I am stuck on the how to return a value back to jquery to say it was a successful insert into the db or not.

Here is the code i am using at the moment.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('.add-vote-link').click( function () 
{
    var img_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "/votes/vote/" + img_id,  
            //  data: "img_id="+ img_id,  
                success: function()
        {  
                    //$('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});   
            $('#vote_counter_'+img_id).html(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
                }  
    });
});
});
```

html to update:

```
<div id="vote_counter_<?php echo $img['Images']['img_id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $img['Images']['img_vote_count']; ?>
</div>
```

php is used to submit the data to a db, this works fine also and either returns 1 for a successful insert and 0 if it didnt insert, how do i pass this back to my jquery function and then have an if statement to do the counter ++ or not.

Hope someone can help and iv explained it ok :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If everything is perfect, you only need is to pass the data as json :D

In the page "/votes/vote/" + img_id you should put that it displays json data

the view most be something like this

```
<?php
echo $javascript->object($results);
?>
```

$results should be a array like this

```
$results = array( 'result' => 1, //any other data you want to pass
);
```

and your layout for this should be something like this

```
<?php
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
header('Content-Type: text/x-json');
echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

finally your $.ajax should be something like this

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/votes/vote/" + img_id,  
        //  data: "img_id="+ img_id,
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function( data ){  
                if (data.result == 1){
                     counter++;
                } else {
                  //display error message or something
                }
                $('#vote_counter_'+img_id).html(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
            }  
});
```

Like this you may pass any data to your jquery after the cakephp page execution, hope this works for you :D (I did this from memory so maybe i'm missing something :S)